I'm trying to set up merge replication and I get an error 'MSmerge_ctsv_9777E7338F8248498FD', because it does not exist or you do not have permission
My error is MSmerge_ctsv_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D, because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
I connected to the subscriber database and tried to execute the following query:
exec sys.sp_MSaddmergetriggers N'Employees', N'dbo', null, 0 

and got the following error: sp_MS_marksystemobject: 

Invalid object name '[dbo].[MSmerge_ins_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D]'
sp_MS_marksystemobject: Invalid object name '[dbo].[MSmerge_upd_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D]'
sp_MS_marksystemobject: Invalid object name '[dbo].[MSmerge_del_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D]'
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 Cannot find the object 'MSmerge_ctsv_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Failed to create merge replication triggers for object '[dbo].[Employees]'.

Completion time: 2024-10-23T15:03:16.5001483-04:00
What permits do I need?
Maybe the following has some effect: if I execute the following query on the publishers:
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'MSmerge_ctsv_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D';

I get one record, if I execute this query on the subscriber, I don't find a single record

This error stems from missing system tables and triggers related to MSmerge_ctsv_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D on the subscriber. You can carry out the following to try to resolve this issue:

Check on the permissions - Ensure the user being used for replication has db_owner permissions on the publisher and the subscriber database.

Since the affected object is related to the Msmerge_ctsv table,  reinitializing the subscription to ensure the necessary replication objects are recreated on the subscriber database can help resolve this issue. Once you reinitialize the subscription, start the snapshot agent for data synchronization on the publisher.

Run DBCC CHECKDB on both databases, to check metadata corruption that may be causing replication failure.


